# Rails association using extracted year from "date" column as foreign key?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two models:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # birthday: date
end

class BirthYear < ActiveRecord::Base
  # year: int
  # people_count: int
end
```

Is there a way to create an association between `year` in BirthYear and `date` in Person?  My goal is to keep track of how many `people` were born in a given year, and track when that number changes.

I basically want to use `date` as a primary key with the SQL condition that:

```
 extract(year from people.birthday) = birth_year.year
```

EDIT: Note I would like to use a counter_cache if possible, which is why I was thinking of using a separate model.  I would like to avoid counting the records with `extract` every time I use the count value.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure `BirthYear` as you described it warrants a separate model.

How about this?

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # birthday: date

  def self.born_in_year_count(year)
    self.where('extract(year from birthday) = ?', year).count
  end

  def birth_year
    birthday.year
  end
end

Person.born_in_year_count(1990)
```

Comment: I see.  The only problem (and I'm sorry for not mentioning this) is I would like to use a counter_cache to avoid having to do the count via SQL each time.  Do you have an idea of how to do this?

Comment: You *could* use [conditional counter_cache](http://douglasfshearer.com/2006/10/06/custom-counter-cache-with-conditions.html), but two models here just rub me the wrong way (kind of ugly). If you don't want to use `extract` in your query, split up birthday into `day`, `month` and `year`, so you can have a simplier where condition

Answer (score 0):

If you need to track change of people born in given year, try to implement `before_create` callback for `Person` model (maybe you'll need to add `after_destroy` callback to track user removal):

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  # birthday: date
  before_create :do_some_stuff

  # ...
  private

  def do_some_stuff
    # ...
  end
end
```

Seems like `BirthYear` model exist just for indexing.

Comment: I'd like to have the count available in the database (I was thinking as a counter cache), but do you think I should just add a new column to the `Person` database for that, and update it on creation/deletion?

Comment: In the case if you don't need to access users count (for selected year) often, it is easier not to add new model with just two fields.